# Modal Window in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, cocoa-sheet

I'm trying to create a custom modal window and here is the code I have so far:

```
NSWindowController *modalSheet = [[NSWindowController alloc]
initWithWindowNibName:@"MyCustomWindow" owner:self];

[NSApp beginSheet:[modalSheet window]
 modalForWindow:[self windowForSheet]
  modalDelegate:nil
 didEndSelector:nil
    contextInfo:nil];
```

The window pops up fine but it's not modal e.g. you can still do things to the parent window where the requests come from. This method is called from an NSDocument object.

I've tried to read: [Using Custom Sheets](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html)

However i'm not sure what `myCustomSheet` is as it's not declared anywhere. I assume it's an `NSWindow` instance variable.

I just can't understand why it's not modal. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Hope this helps.
To run your window controller always modal. Create your own subclass of NSWindowController and add this two methods.

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{//TODO
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:self.window];
    });
}

- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a section of Apple's Window Programming Guide dedicated specifically to [Using Modal Windows](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html) which tells you pretty much everything you should need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance got `worksWhenModal` set to `YES`?  This would cause *exactly* the behaviour you describe, since that's the purpose of it.

With regards to wrapping the panel (you're using a NSPanel, right?) in it's own window controller, you don't need to.  I actually just make my sheets without a window controller.  Do you have any custom logic in the window controller that you need?  AppKit handles it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not, reading elsewhere it looks like you can't initialise windows made from a xib file through `NSWindowController`. So I have to figure out how to get a xib file loaded through `NSBundle` into an `NSWindow`.

Comment: Do you really need the XIB?  It bugs me how the documentation often makes it seem like the only way to do something is via a interface builder, when making a window without IB is really simple.

I actually just make my sheets without a window controller.  Do you have any custom logic in the window controller that you need?  AppKit handles it for you.